# Use a parameter or variable to set connection timeout in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

In an effort to simplify SSIS package management, I am trying to set the timeout value to a variable on multiple SSIS packages, so that value can be adjusted using the variable.

However, it seems like it's hard to change that value to use a variable.  I first went to the connection manager, and went to the its Initialization property:

[image]

I tried to enter in the variable value to the "Connect Timeout", but it raised an error "Property Value is not valid" saying that it's int32 value, when the variable was clearly int32 data type.

I tried to resolve the problem in a different way using expressions on the connection manager property.  However, I could not find any way to set the connection time out from there either:

[image]

As you can see above, there is no "Connect Timeout" value I can change using expression.

From the research I did, it seems like "Connect Timeout" value is simply used to build a connection string, and I can indirectly set it using expression setting an expression on "Connection String" instead of on "Connect Timeout".  Is that the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unfortunately yes**, the only way is to build ConnectionString property using expression.

The main cause is that Timeout property [is not a member of SSIS ConnectionManager.Properties property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.connectionmanager.properties?view=sqlserver-2017). To prove that, click on the OLE DB connection manager and press <kbd>F4</kbd> to show the properties window, you will not find *Connection Timeout* property in the connection manager properties.

[image]